# Issue with CSV MIME Type not downloading through browser

Tags: php, mysql, file, http-headers, export-to-csv

so, first let me state, before you start providing other suggestions on how to simply export a complete table to a CSV file, that is not what I want to do (my demo code right now suggests that, but I am merely testing the whole downloading through browser shabaz).

I actually want to construct my content to be exported from several tables. never the less, I am merely trying to get the exporting and downloading through the browser working right now.

I got this code from an example online and currently what is happening is it is simply printing out the data to my browser.

here is my code I am testing:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM results_tb") or die(mysql_error());

    // I hard-code the column names so I can capitalize, add spaces, etc.
    $fields = '"User ID","Test_id","score %","Time taken"'."\n";

    // Iterate through the rows of data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //echo $row['user_id'];
        $fields .= '"'.$row['user_id'].'","'.$row['test_id'].'","'.$row['score'].'","'.$row['time_elapsed'].'"'."\n";
    }

    // Set our headers
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    // To display data in-browser, change the header below to:
    // header("Content-Disposition: inline");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=event_registrations.csv");

    // Output our data
    echo $fields;
```

I am assuming this example is pants, so could somebody explain to me how to do this?

many thanks :D

my header response caught with firebug-Lite:

```
Date    Wed, 18 May 2011 14:15:18 GMT
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.1.6
Content-disposition attachment;filename=MyVerySpecial.csv
Connection  close
Content-Length  992
Server  Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Content-Type    text/csv
```

Comment: Any change if you change the content type to application/octet-stream? If so, then your browser wants to handle all text/* types and ignores disposition.

Comment: hi thanks, unfortnately, I get the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have `display_errors` set to off, and you're outputting something before those `header()` calls are made. That would cause the behaviour you are seeing.

First off, edit your `php.ini` file and make sure that `display_errors` is on and that you have error reporting on in your PHP script (e.g. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`). Now you will probably get an error on your screen. Something along the lines of:

```
Cannot send header information. Output already started by XXX.php (line YYY).
```

What is probably happening is that you are accidentally sending a space or a newline before you are sending the `header()` commands, and you're suppressing the error. When you send something to the browser before those `header()` calls, they will be ignored. So, the browser will just display whatever you're sending instead of letting the user download it.

If you're using Firefox, you can also use the Firebug extension to check the HTTP response headers of your download.

Comment: ok, so I tried setting the display errors. getting no error out. I have edited my post to include the HTTP response header.